# Remove inner white spaces in text data with SQL

Tags: sql, whitespace, teradata

All I have what seems to be a pretty straight forward question, that I haven't been able to figure out.  For example, if I have a text string like `T6L 7H5`.  Using SQL I need to remove the inner white space from this string so that it displays like `T6L7H5`.

Things to consider:

- Teradata (v.13.10) is my RDBMS, so `REPLACE('T6L 7H5', ' ', '')` is not an
  option here.
- On this particular server I am a business user w/ very limited
  permissions so creating a UDF is not an option either.

Comment: Have you tried `oreplace()`?

Comment: I'm running Teradata 13, so unfortunately `oreplace()` isn't an option

Comment: Are Position and Substring available in that version?

Comment: @Goat_CO, yes those functions are available

Comment: Are you removing a single white space or multiple?

Comment: @RobPaller, For the field I'm working with I only need to be able to remove the 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single white space you can use `POSITION()` and `SUBSTRING()`. You have to offset for the whitespace location that is returned by the `POSITION()` function.

```
   WITH CTE(FieldName) AS
    (SELECT 'TB7 TCH' AS FieldName)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(FieldName FROM 1 FOR (POSITION(' ' IN FieldName) - 1)) 
            || SUBSTRING(FieldName FROM (POSITION(' ' IN FieldName) + 1))
    FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't test this, so spit-balling, but you should be able to leverage Substring and Position:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('T6L 7H5', 1, POSITION (' ' IN 'T6L 7H5')-1) || SUBSTRING('T6L 7H5',  POSITION (' ' IN 'T6L 7H5')+1, CHARACTER_LENGTH('T6L 7H5') -  POSITION (' ' IN 'T6L 7H5') )
```

If the field is consistently formatted like your example then:

```
substring('T6L 7H5',1,3)||substring('T6L 7H5',4,3)
```

Comment: Goat, there's a small syntax error in the code you posted. But I made a slight change (edited the post) and it gets me the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using  substr( );
Ex :  4= start at position 4 && 1 = delete one char.

```
   substr(Table1.fieldname, 4,1)
```